# How to loop css with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

Firstly I want to state that I understand that html is not the best for printing but for what I need it works fine. That being said I want to setup a page with absolute positioning that will repeat itself and have a page break after each page. I've seen how to add page breaks if you do NOT use absolute positioning but how do you do it with absolute positioning?

Below is my non-working code:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
div#valueLocation {
  left: 20px;
  top: 305px;
}
.page-break {
  clear: left;
  display:block;
  page-break-after:always;
}
```

```html
<div id="valueLocation">Name1</div>
<p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
<div id="valueLocation">Name2</div>
<p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
<div id="valueLocation">Name3</div>
```

The above code causes Names 1, 2, and 3 to overlap. How can I make each restart from it's own page? And if it's not possible how can I have several elements on my page be positioned at specific locations so that I can have page breaks? Again I understand that you cannot pixel perfect guarantee what's printed but for my needs the above is works very well.

PS: I also included the style I used as well as the inline style just to show some different options I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible with just html/css.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are overlapping is because they all have the same id. You give all three names this styling:

```
div#valueLocation
{
    left: 20px;
    top: 305px;
}
```

The styling sets their position, hence they all show up in the same spot (20px from the left and 305px from the top). It has nothing to do with your page breaks.

Comment: In my actual code it's in a loop, so I need to be able to use the same ID. That being said I understand why it doesn't work but I also couldn't get it to work with class=""

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the desired result then you have to use `JavaScript` to calculate the position and apply it dynamically. Or If you still need to do from CSS then here is one way but not a suggested one.

You can `nth-child` property to target the elements.

```
 div#valueLocation
{
    left: 20px;
    top: 305px;
}
div#valueLocation:nth-child(2)
{
   top: 350px;
}
div#valueLocation:nth-child(3)
{
   top: 400px;
}
```

Like the above you just created some 10 elements and control that loop not exceeded more than 10.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/qw5jbywk/)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Javascript :(

Comment: Then you can try with the above `CSS` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Names 1,2 and 3 are overlapping because `position: absolute` works with relative to a parent element which has `position: relative`, if none, then the root element. In your case, all will refer to the root element, i.e. `body` in your case. So, all are overlapping.

To solve this, you have to give different styles to all the divs. You can hardcode values and make it work.

As mentioned in another answer, you can use this approach. But as you should use id only once in an HTML. Use `class` instead:

```css
div.valueLocation {
  left: 20px;
  top: 305px;
}

div.valueLocation:nth-child(2) {
  top: 350px; // you have to add the height of the first child and give top for the second
}

div.valueLocation:nth-child(3) {
  top: 400px; // add heights of 1st and 2nd accordingly for 3rd as position: absolute is relative to the body.
}

<body>
  <div class="valueLocation">Name1</div>
  <p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
  <div class"valueLocation">Name2</div>
  <p style="page-break-after: always;"></p>
  <div class="valueLocation">Name3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The html is generated in a loop and could contain a LOT of entries. I can't imagine it would work well with say 500 pages...